# Is there a built-in concurrency control in boost::interprocess::message_queue?

Tags: boost, boost-interprocess

In a multiple producer-single consumer setting, is there a built-in concurrency control mechanism among the producer processes that are calling `send()` on the *message_queue*?

What happens if there are multiple instances of the consumer processes all calling `receive()` on the *message_queue*?

Comment: Access control or concurrency control? Those are very different

Comment: Changed the title to concurrency control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the question whether `message_queue` is thread-safe, the answer is yes.

`message_queue` is implemented in terms of `shared_memory_object` using some control structures (`ipcdetail::mq_hdr_t`) which include synchronization primitives (like `interprocess_mutex`).

These are used to prevent unguarded concurrent access.